# publish multiple data on one topic

Tags: ros, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is it possible to publish multiple data i.e angle for servo1 and angle for servo2 on one topic ? If yes, please show me answer how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit:  Thank you sir for your answer.

But still getting the error as "Segmentation fault(core dumped)"

Please consider my procedure:

```
sensor_msgs::JointState joint;
joint.position[1] = 50;
joint.velocity[1] = 100;
joint.effort[1] = 90;

dd.publish(joint);

qDebug() << "position =" << joint.position[1];
qDebug() << "velocity =" << joint.velocity[1];
qDebug() << "effort =" << joint.effort[1];
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226754/publish-multiple-data-on-one-topic/) by [darshandoria](https://answers.ros.org/users/23601/darshandoria/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2016-02-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-16**:
@darshandoria: please don't post answers to provide us with more information. Edit your question for that. Use the *edit* link/button.

**Comment by [darshandoria](https://answers.ros.org/users/23601/darshandoria/) on 2016-02-16**:
ok i will take care of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The vectors containing position, velocity and effort default to a size of zero. You either have to use `push_back` or resize the vectors before writing to them.

```
sensor_msgs::JointState joint;
joint.position.push_back(50);
joint.velocity.push_back(100);
joint.effort.push_back(90);
```

or

```
sensor_msgs::JointState joint;
joint.position.resize(1);
joint.velocity.resize(1);
joint.effort.resize(1);
joint.position[0] = 50;
joint.velocity[0] = 100;
joint.effort[0] = 90;
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [darshandoria](https://answers.ros.org/users/23601/darshandoria/) on 2016-02-16**:
Thank You so much all of you !!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use a sensor_msgs::JointState http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html, and fill name and position with your values.
Or you create a custom message that contains two floats: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1